# NullReferenceException in GetCachedPen function of DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We are having a NullReferenceException in the DataGridView of WinForms.  Actually we are using the DataGridViewX component from DotNetBar however this is a fairly simple wrapper around the standard DataGridView so I have reason to believe it is not responsible for the issue.  The stack trace is:

```
Unhandled thread exception System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCachedPen(Color color)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle clipRect, Rectangle bounds)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.DataGridViewX.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I cannot find any posts on any sites for a similar error.

I reviewed the code for this function at the [.NET Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com), and this (internal/Friend) function takes a Color and looks inside a private hash table of cached pens:

```
internal Pen GetCachedPen(Color color)
{
    Pen pen = (Pen) this.pens[color];
    if (pen == null)
    {
        pen = new Pen(color);
        this.pens.Add(color, pen);
    }
    return pen;
}
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,205118801a8f1ca9

The only way I can see this possibly crashing is if the Color passed in is null, however the only time I can see this function get called is:

```
if (paintingNeeded)
{
    if (this.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.Fixed3D)
    {
        if (Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
        {
            Pen pen = GetCachedPen(VisualStyleInformation.TextControlBorder);
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, bounds.Width - 1, bounds.Height - 1));
        }
        else
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(g, bounds, Border3DStyle.Sunken);
        }
    }
    else if (this.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle)
    {
        Pen pen = GetCachedPen(SystemColors.ControlText);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, bounds.Width - 1, bounds.Height - 1));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Fail("DataGridView.PaintBorder - Unexpected BorderStyle value.");
    }
}
```

The BorderStyle of the DGV is set to BorderStyle.FixedSingle, so the color parameter getting passed to GetCachedPen should be SystemColors.ControlText, which for me should never be null?

I have found some posts of seemingly "random" crashes from the DGV related to painting, but none seemed to have a solution and none were related to the GetCachedPen function.  Looking at our error logging database we can see this has crashed our software 3 times in the last couple of years since we started asking our users to submit crash logs, so its certainly not something systematic we are doing wrong as this is a well used part of the software.

Has anyone seen this crash before, or something similar?  Is there a solution to this?  Alternatively is there some kind of workaround to these painting errors in a WinForms control?

Comment: If you can reproduce the error, have you tried debugging the net framework source? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx https://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html

Comment: No, thank you though.  I did not know about this!  Unfortunately so far we have not been able to reproduce the issue ourselves, but at least we can try to gain a bit more understanding of the values involved by stepping through the code.  I'll give it a god and see what I can find.

Comment: I'd start by replacing the custom component with the .NET DGV component.  Then you'd know for sure if it was the custom component or the .NET component.

Comment: Unfortunately releasing the software in this state would be a last resort as the custom component is used throughout the software and interfaces with the "gobal style manager".  We had someone unsuccessfully spend a day trying to reproduce internally.  If you look at the functions involved, I can't see how it can be the custom component: GetCachedPen is an internal function, pens is a private variable, and the PaintBorder function that GetCachedPen is called from is private (this was not mentioned in my original post).  Unless I'm missing something obvious, this rules out the custom component?

Comment: In the end we did replace the custom component with the standard .NET DGV, but are still having the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. But very strange I receive it only on my laptop (Windows 10), on my workstation (Windows 7) I don't have this problem.
On my laptop I receive the error consistently. A form is openend for editing, I do some editing, click on Save, then I close the form and I always receive the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCachedPen(Color color)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.PaintBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle clipRect, Rectangle bounds)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I don't know why this is happening on only some computers but I fixed the problem as follows.
The datagrid is in my case also wrapped in my own usercontrol. In the usercontrol you can override the OnPaint event.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)
    Try
        ' Dispose I will not do anything if done.
        If Not Me.IsDisposed Then
            MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        Else
            Debug.Print("SingleRecordDatagrid: Datagridview already disposed.")
        End If

    Catch ex As NullReferenceException
        ' Even if you give an exception, don't do anything.
        Debug.Print("SingleRecordDatagrid: " & ex.Message & "  StackTrace: " & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Thanks, in the end we went with this approach to solve the problem.  The one further thing we learned is that it was happening only on laptops with touchscreens.  Disabling the touchscreen in the Device Manager fixed the problem...